# In VSCode how to properly configure jsconfig.json in order for absolute paths with index.js imports to work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, path, visual-studio-code

In my React project, where `./` is the root directory, I have configured webpack so that I can import any file from within my `./src` directory.

For example, consider the following directory structure:

```
./
|-src/
| |-components/
| | |-Button/
| | | |-index.js
| | | |-Button.jsx
```

where `src/components/Button/index.js` contains just this:

`export { default } from './Button';`

Now let's say I create another component in `src/components/NewComponent`, which is structured similarly to `src/components/Button`, but inside my `NewComponent.jsx` I am doing the following:

`import Button from 'components/Button'`

The above compiles just fine because I have set up my webpack correctly.

What I would like to be able to do, is for VSCode to be able to take me to the definition of the `Button` component when I `alt+click` on the word `Button` of the `import` statement, and take me to the `index.js` file's contents when I `alt+click` on the `components/Button` part.

I cannot seem to be able to do that.

My `jsconfig.json` is the following, as of the time of writing:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "src/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "build", "dist"]
}
```

And, for good measure, the relevant part of my webpack config:

```
const PATHS = {
  node_modules: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
  src: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
  style: path.resolve(__dirname, 'style'),
  assets: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets'),
  test: path.resolve(__dirname, 'test')
};

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      path.resolve(__dirname),
      PATHS.node_modules,
      PATHS.src,
      PATHS.style,
      PATHS.assets,
      PATHS.test
    ],
    mainFiles: ['index', 'index.js', 'index.jsx', 'index.scss'],
    extensions: ['.jsx', '.js', '.json', '.scss', '.css']
  },
....
```

Answer (score 3):

I think your configuration is correct the only mistake you've made is in the *path* setting.

Try this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "components/*": ["./src/components/*/index"]
    }
  },
  “Include”: [“./src/**/*”],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "build", "dist"]
}
```

or just type `import Button from 'src/components/Button'`

after this close-reopen the project et voilà ;)